# Distinct operation on a batch pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, distinct-values

From the [apache doc on Distinct](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Distinct.html): `Distinct<T> takes a PCollection<T> and returns a PCollection<T> that has all distinct elements of the input. Thus, each element is unique within each window.`

What is more, if I'm not mistaken unless specified otherwise in a batch processing on Dataflow 2.5.0, all the elements are part of the same window.

This would imply that a `Distinct` stage in a linear pipeline would apply to all the elements. However, I have observed that the stages after `Distinct` could already start processing before the `Distinct` stage was finished (=some elements has not gone through it yet). What is more, the `Distinct` stage seems to require very little computing power (as seen on the visualisation console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/jobsDetail/...), which is unexpected because finding duplicates in millions of inputs seems like a consequent task to me.

So my question is the following: **Does a `Distinct` stage on a linear pipeline with batch processing indeed apply to ALL the elements of the batch ?** Am I missing something ?

An example pipeline:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p.apply("Stuff", ParDo.of(new Stuff())
 .apply(Distinct.<String>create())
 .apply("OtherStuff", ParDo.of(new OtherStuff())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it applies to all elements. Basically, there is no issue when stages after the distinct operation already start processing. The distinct operation only needs to suppress duplicates, but the first observation of an element can be processed.

Please take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/279a05604b83a54e8e5a79e13d8761f94841f326/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Distinct.java#L102) to see how it works internally since it basically consists of a simple `Combine.perKey` operation without aggregating any value.